# How to get lat and long from google map circle

Tags: javascript, dictionary

[image]

I want to get lat and long at A,B,C,D Position in this google map circle how can I do that?

Comment: Can you be more specific like what is known? For example, is the radius of circle known? Is the lat/long of center position known?

Comment: A and B will have the same longitude as the center; C and D will have the same latitude.  If you know the radius, you can then use the Haversine formula to derive the change in one element.